# find difference between any two columns of dataframes with a common key column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with one having

```
Title  Name Quantity ID
```

as the columns

and the 2nd dataframe has

```
ID Quantity
```

as the columns with lesser number of rows than first dataframe .

I need to find the difference between the Quantity of both dataframes based the match in the ID columns and I want to store this difference in a seperate column in the first dataframe .

> I tried this (did't work) :

```
DF1[['ID','Quantity']].reset_index(drop=True).apply(lambda id_qty_tup  : DF2[DF2.ID==asin_qty_tup[0]].quantity - id_qty_tup[1] , axis = 1)
```

Another approach is to apply the ID and quantity of DF1 and iterate through each row of DF2 but it takes more time . Im sure there is a better way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` in this case:

```
df['diff'] = df['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID').Quantity) - df.Quantity
```

---

## Some Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
                   'Name': ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'EE'],
                   'Quantity': [1, 21, 14, 15, 611],
                   'ID': ['A1', 'A1', 'B2', 'B2', 'C1']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Quantity': [11, 51, 44],
                    'ID': ['A1', 'B2', 'C1']})
```

We will use `df2` to create a dictionary which can be used to map `ID` to `Quantity`. So anywhere there is an `ID==A1` in `df` it gets assigned the Quantity 11, `B2` gets assigned 51 and `C1` gets assigned 44. Here' I'll add it as another column just for illustration purposes.

```
df['Quantity2'] = df['ID'].map(df2.set_index('ID').Quantity)
print(df)

   ID Name  Quantity Title  Quantity2
0  A1   AA         1     A         11
1  A1   BB        21     B         11
2  B2   CC        14     C         51
3  B2   DD        15     D         51
4  C1   EE       611     E         44
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Then you can just subtract `df['Quantity']` and the column we just created to get the difference. (Or subtract that from `df['Quantity']` if you want the other difference)

Comment: @Nateshbhat hopefully that edit clears things up. If you need more information let me know, or you can always check out the documentation for [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can perform index-aligned subtraction, and pandas takes care of the rest.

```
df['Diff'] = df.set_index('ID').Quantity.sub(df2.set_index('ID').Quantity).values
```

---

**Demo**
Here, changetype is the index, and I've already set it, so `pd.Series.sub` will align subtraction by default. Otherwise, you'd need to set the index as above.

```
df1
                      strings      test
changetype                             
0                     a very  -1.250150
1            very boring text -1.376637
2            I cannot read it -1.011108
3                 Hi everyone -0.527900
4             please go home  -1.010845
5               or I will go   0.008159
6                         now -0.470354

df2
                                     strings      test
changetype                                            
0                    a very very boring text  0.625465
1                           I cannot read it -1.487183
2                                Hi everyone  0.292866
3            please go home or I will go now  1.430081

df1.test.sub(df2.test)

changetype
0   -1.875614
1    0.110546
2   -1.303974
3   -1.957981
4         NaN
5         NaN
6         NaN
Name: test, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @Nateshbhat See example. Works for me.